# Is there a way to show a calculated result (updating anytime there is a change) from a few input boxes without actually pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, html, io, event-handling, dom-events

I am currently writing a simple calculator as an exercise.

I have a few input fields where the user can put certain values, then clicking a button
a function is triggered where it does some calculations and shows the output in a table.

The input I am interested in is the following:

```html
<p>Total eligible voters:
    <input type="text" id="totalVoters" name="totalVoters" placeholder="0">
</p>

<p>Voter turnout:
    <input type="text" id="voterTurnout" name="voterTurnout" placeholder="0">
</p>

<p>Percentage of ineligible bulletins:
    <input type="text" id="ineligibleBulletins" name="ineligibleBulletins" placeholder="0">
</p>
<br><br>
```

Once that data is filled, the user has to fill however many votes they wish each party to receive.
I can't figure out (a simple) way to show however many votes are still unaccounted for.

For example, if the user puts totalVoters = 1000 , voterTurnout = 50% , ineligibleBulletins = 10%
the total unaccounted votes are (1-0.1)(*0.5*1000) = 450.

And as the user starts filling the other field for voters per each party, say party1 = 50, I want to show (somewhere) however many (unaccounted) votes there are left, in this case 400.

I was considering some kind of a loop, but can't really figure out how to update the unaccountedVotes once a change occurs. Using JS.

Comment: Did you try it with the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)? You could listen for changes on all elements with a specific class (e.g. `.vote-input`) and then update it accordingly. Alternatively there's also a input event similar to the change event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One would choose kind of a component-based approach which

- forces a cleaner / better structured markup,
- calls for a scripting approach which in a lean way initializes a component and encapsulates the component related data/references ... and therefore ...
- enables code-reuse.

After coming up with an improved markup where a component can be identified by its root-node, one would [query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) any available root-node and start each component's initialization.

As for the OP's case one would implement a handler-function which is `this`-context aware and therefore receives all relevant component-data via a [bound context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Here one would query and bind all relevant element-nodes for input and output which allows both, registering the handler-function which was created by `bind` and [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)ing the component's initial and updating render-process.

In addition the chosen `'range'`-type  input-element gets enhanced by rendering its current range-value via an [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) CSS [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), its [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) based [CSS generated content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Generated_Content) and a simple `input`-type event-handler which writes the element's `value` (the property) into the elements `value`-attribute.

In both cases, registering the value-update of an enhanced range-element and registering a component's update-handling, one would choose the [`'input'` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

```js
function updateRangePseudoContent({ currentTarget }) {
  currentTarget
    .setAttribute('value', currentTarget.value);
}
function updateUnaccountedVotesFromBoundContext() {
  const { output, total, turnout, ineligible } = this;
  output
    .value = Math.round(
      (1 - (ineligible.valueAsNumber / 100)) *
      (turnout.valueAsNumber / 100) *
      total.valueAsNumber
    );
}

function initializeEachUnaccountedVotesCalculator() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-unaccounted-votes-calculator] [type="range"]')
    .forEach(elmNode =>
      elmNode.addEventListener('input', updateRangePseudoContent)
    );
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-unaccounted-votes-calculator]')
    .forEach(rootNode => {

      const output = rootNode
        .querySelector('output');
      const total = rootNode
        .querySelector('[data-name="total-voters"]');
      const turnout = rootNode
        .querySelector('[data-name="voter-turnout"]');
      const ineligible = rootNode
        .querySelector('[data-name="ineligible-bulletins"]');

      rootNode
        .addEventListener(
          'input',
          updateUnaccountedVotesFromBoundContext
            .bind({ output, total, turnout, ineligible })
        );

      // initialization via all the current element's data.
      updateUnaccountedVotesFromBoundContext
        .call({ output, total, turnout, ineligible });
    });
}

initializeEachUnaccountedVotesCalculator();
```

```css
fieldset {
  width: 70%;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
fieldset, label {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
label {
  width: 90%;
}
label, label > span, label > input {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
label > span::after {
  content: ':';
}
[type="range"] {
  width: calc(100% - 10px - 4em);
}
[type="range"]::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
  content: attr(value)' %';
  width: 4em;
  height: 1em,
}
output {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<fieldset data-unaccounted-votes-calculator>
  <label>
    <span>Total eligible voters</span>
    <input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="1000" data-name="total-voters">
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Voter turnout</span>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="0.1" data-name="voter-turnout">
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Percentage of ineligible bulletins</span>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="10" step="0.1" data-name="ineligible-bulletins">
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Unaccounted votes</span>
    <output>0</output>
  </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset data-unaccounted-votes-calculator>
  <label>
    <span>Total eligible voters</span>
    <input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="25000" data-name="total-voters">
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Voter turnous</span>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="70" step="0.1" data-name="voter-turnout">
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Percentage of ineligible bulletins</span>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="5" step="0.1" data-name="ineligible-bulletins">
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Unaccounted votes</span>
    <output>0</output>
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74789362/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-calculated-result-updating-anytime-there-is-a-change/74792752#comment131997439_74792752) @PeterSeliger I downvoted after you [originally posted a code-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74792752/1) and then retracted my downvote after you provided an explanation: see [answer]. Including "explanation incoming" (or similar) isn't a substitute for answer substance: please refrain from posting until your answer is actually ready.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74789362/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-calculated-result-updating-anytime-there-is-a-change/74792752#comment131997796_74792752) This site has seen plenty of [FGITW](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=fastest%20gun%20in%20the%20west) behavior and I think we should focus on **quality** over speed, especially as the rate of new content on the site continues to accelerate.

Comment: @jsejcksn ... I understand the attitude and I personally manage to avoid almost always to provide code only answers, especially for complex approaches. Thats why the initial answer got shipped with the ... _"+ + + explanation in progress + + +"_ ... disclaimer which stayed there for about half an hour. Lately I quite often encountered closed questions after spending 1 to 2 hours answering them and especially explaining the approaches which tempts me now to answer early with the mentioned disclaimer in order to fight the discouraging events.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to stay as close to the OP original code as possible and created a hybrid solution with use of CSS *custom properties* and *Javascript*.

- Created parent `#input` wrapper to hold three CSS *custom properties* with current entered 'Voter' values.
- Attached a simple JS function to the inline *oninput* attribute of each `input` element. This JS function assigns the currently typed `input` value to a CSS *custom property*. Using *onchange* would work too, but requires the user to hit [Enter] first where *oninput* is immediate.
- Create *Javascript* function `showInput()` which retrieves the current input values from the updated CSS *custom properties*. It calculates the current *Unaccounted Voters* value, rounds it to two decimals with function `toDecimals()` and assigns it to the `#output` element to show the intermediate result.
- CSS `#output::after` shows a little trick how to assign the value of a CSS *custom property* to the CSS `counter()` to display it with `content`. Unfortunately `counter()` only returns integer values, otherwise use of *Javascript* function `showOutput()` could have been skipped.

```css
#input {
    --total      /* current 'Total eligible voters' value */
    --turnout    /* current 'Voter turnout' percentage */
    --ineligible /* current 'Ineligible bulletins' percentage */
}

#output {
    --unaccounted /* calculated value current 'Unaccounted Voters' */
}
```

**Snippet** with comments in the code...

```js
// Show updated output
function showOutput() {
    // Get reference to the output info element
    const output = document.getElementById('output');
    const style  = getComputedStyle(output); // Compute current style values

    // Retrieve the current, inherited CSS variable values
    let total      = style.getPropertyValue('--total');
    let turnout    = style.getPropertyValue('--turnout');
    let ineligible = style.getPropertyValue('--ineligible');

    // Do the calculation and show the intermediate result, rounded to 2 decimals
    output.innerHTML =  'Unaccounted Voters: ' + toDecimals((1 - ineligible / 100) * turnout / 100 * total).toFixed(2);
};

// Round a value to a given number of decimals
function toDecimals(value, decimals = 2) { // default is 2 decimals
  return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
};

showOutput(); // First run
```

```css
#input {
    /* Initialize CSS custum properties in parent wrapper */
    --total     : 0; /* these get modified by <input> oninput event */
    --turnout   : 0;
    --ineligible: 0;
}

#output {
    /* Calculate current unaccounted value on the fly */
    --unaccounted: calc( (1 - var(--ineligible) / 100) * var(--turnout) / 100 * var(--total) );
}

/* Alternative without using JS, rounded to integer by counter mechanism */
/* #output innerHTML gets modified by JS, but attached ::after is done here... */
#output::after {
     /* workaround to display content of a CSS custom property */
    counter-reset: unaccounted var(--unaccounted); /* Assign the current value */
    content: ' / counter(' counter(unaccounted) ')';
}
```

```html
<div id="input"><!-- main wrapper with defined CSS custom properties -->
    <p>Total eligible voters:
        <input type="number" id="totalVoters" name="totalVoters" placeholder="0"
               min="0" max="1500" step="1" value="0"
               oninput="document.getElementById('input').style.setProperty('--total', this.value);
                        showOutput();">
    </p>

    <p>Voter turnout %:
        <input type="number" id="voterTurnout" name="voterTurnout" placeholder="0"
               min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0"
               oninput="document.getElementById('input').style.setProperty('--turnout', this.value);
                        showOutput();">
    </p>

    <p>Ineligible bulletins %:
        <input type="number" id="ineligibleBulletins" name="ineligibleBulletins" placeholder="0"
               min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0"
               oninput="document.getElementById('input').style.setProperty('--ineligible', this.value);
                        showOutput();">
    </p>
    <p id="output"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the custom css property approach. I learned a lot ... +1.

Comment: @PeterSeliger tnx! Not really for production, but fun approach for quick and dirty demos. Baseline: define some vars at parent level, let kids/anything change them, process results at kids level. Here's a [different subject on codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/JjpeaZX) you can toy with. Scaling entire content and `ellipsis` vs. `line-clamp`. Same principles...

Answer (score -2):

I would try setting up an event listener for changes made to the inputs. Then have it update the output whenever a change is made. But I'm fairly new to programming and there could be a simpler way.